# WPF pass object from control to controltemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I'm trying to pass an object from a control, in this case a RadioButton, to its control template.  From there, in the template I want to display the SampleNo string property in the templated control.  See the image below, which illustrates it better.  Can you guys guide me as to what I'm doing wrong?

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbe2W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can ues datacontext, just like below:
[image]
then you can binding some object to your control's datacontext(If the object has a name attribute ):
[image]

Comment: I think that gets me close, but I'm getting the following error.  
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Button', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SampleNo; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name='RatingTemplate'); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Comment: As you can only see from the images you gave, you used togglebutton instead of button, they are all subclass of buttonbase, so they are not interchangeable.However, the button class appears from your error message, and it is clear that you used button instead of togglebutton.

Comment: Thank you Nabian, that worked.  Saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the code as shown below
[image]

Comment: That won't work.  If I were doing it that way it would be Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content.SampleNo}" and it says nested types are not supported.  My goal is to pass the entire object up to the ControlTemplate, then cherry pick off properties from it to display.